# How can an imageView link to an activity?

Tags: android

I am new in android

I want to go to a new activity by pressing on an image.

What is the code to do this? Please any help?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like so (attach click listener to `ImageView`-> create new `Intent` with a desired activity as target -> start this activity):

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageView1:
                intent.setClass(MyCurrentActivity.this, HelloActivity.class);
                break;
            case R.id.imageView2:
                intent.setClass(MyCurrentActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        startActivity(intent);

    }
};
imageView1.setOnClickListener(listener);
imageView2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank You :) But if I have many images each having a different id , Where do I specify the id of the image that I want to press?

Comment: @user3385185 what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean, in my case I have 2 images(Image1 and Image2) in an activity named options,When the user press Image1 I want to go to an activity called Hello for example , and when he press Image2 I want to go to another activity called About. But in the code above, there's no place to specify the id of the image to be pressed

Comment: @user3385185 Ok, I've made an edit. You can check the id of the View fired event inside your listener.